# Using IWorkspace.Exists() method?

Tags: arcobjects, workspace

I have a valid and existent workspace (file geodatabase) in a specific folder.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void WorkspaceHandler_TestConstructor_FileGdbWorkspace()
    {
        workHandler = new WorkspaceHandler(gdbWorkspace);

        IWorkspace workspace = workHandler.GetCurrentWorkspace;

        Assert.AreEqual(gdbWorkspace, workspace.PathName);
        Assert.AreEqual(esriWorkspaceType.esriLocalDatabaseWorkspace, workspace.Type);
        Assert.AreEqual(false, workspace.IsDirectory());
        Assert.AreEqual(true, workspace.Exists());
    }
```

My last assert fails. All the other ones are working OK.

Is there any sort of specificity on this particular method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce this with 9.3.1 - I'd call it a bug.  I never use this method.  Instead, I use IWorkspaceFactory.IsWorkspace.  The help doc says IWorkspace.Exists is there so you can detect if the underlying files for a workspace have been deleted by another app.  I'd bet IsWorkspace  can do this too, but I'd check.

Comment: Thanks for the info Kirk. All uses os Exists() fails. This on 9.3.1 too. Should I call ESRI? :P

Comment: Shapefile workspaces return true for Exists() for me. ESRI's gotten  a lot more responsive about bugs lately, you might give it a try.  (If you can reproduce on 10.0 I bet they'd be more responsive though).

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug which was fixed in ArcGIS 10.0.